# Problem with scp on Mac OS X: scp doesn't like spaces in filenames, "\" fix doesn't work

Tags: macos, path, ssh, scp

I am trying to use scp to transfer files between two Macs (OS 10.6.8).  But it fails because there are spaces in my directory/file names.  I can't change the directory/file names.

I have often used a \ symbol when working in a terminal with my Macs to represent spaces.  In this case, however, it is not working.  I would very much appreciate any tips on how to deal with this.  Thanks.

Here is an example of what I'm doing, in case I'm making a silly mistake somewhere:

```
scp -r me@myWork:../../My\ documents/Projects/Project\ 1/* ./Desktop

Error: scp: ../../My: No such file or directory
```

I tried rsync too and that doesn't work either:

```
rsync -avub -e ssh me@myWork::../../My\ documents/Projects/Project\ 1/* ./Desktop

rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-40/rsync/io.c(452)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You didn't escape the space after "my". This:

```
me@myWork:../../My documents/Projects/Project\ 1/*
```

should be:

```
me@myWork:../../My\ documents/Projects/Project\ 1/*
```

Or you could just wrap the entire path in quotes.

Comment: Thanks mipadi.  Sorry--I messed up in my initial post (now edited).  I actually did escape the space and I still get the error, where the escape symbol doesn't seem to be recognized: scp: ../../My: No such file or directory

Comment: Hey, I tried your quotes suggestion.  It worked!!  Thanks so much.  I had never heard of that method.  Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 35):

for me I needed to actually do both:

```
scp -r 127.0.0.1:/Volumes/Folders/Faces/"Why\ Spaces\ Why"/"Insanity\ Rules"/ .
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for **10.14.5 Mojave** and **10.15.7 Catalina**

```
scp -r abc@x.x.x.x:~/Library/MobileDevice/"Provisioning\ Profiles"/. ~/Library/MobileDevice/"Provisioning Profiles"/.
```

Note:

the source path has `"Provisioning\ Profiles"`

the destination path has `"Provisioning Profiles"`

Comment: exactly needed this! 10.15.7 Catalina `scp -r andi@imac:/Users/andi/Music/iTunes/"iTunes\ Media"/Music/"Jacek\ Weigl" /Users/andi/Music/iTunes/"iTunes Media"/"Automatically Add to Music.localized"`