# scp on OSX doesn't allow spaces in usernames?

Tags: windows, ssh, openssh

I need to ssh into a Windows 7 box running [MobaSSH](http://mobassh.mobatek.net/) as its SSH daemon, and the username on the Windows box contains a space.  I can login to the Windows 7 box on an OSX terminal like so:

```
ssh "Some User"@WindowsHost
```

So I thought I'd be able to use the scp command on OSX to transfer files between the computers, but I keep getting an error saying "invalid username" whenever I do something like this:

```
scp myfile "Some User"@WindowsHost:~/myfile
```

I looked into it and found [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697985/problem-with-scp-on-mac-os-x-scp-doesnt-like-spaces-in-filenames-fix-does), but that is mainly about a space within the file paths.

I did find [a bug posted about this issue in a specific version of scp](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1164), but I'm not sure how to patch scp on OSX.  The patch is offered as a .c file.

My last resort is to create a new username on the Windows 7 box and transfer all my profile settings to that new user.  It seems like a real hassle given that I can login via ssh, but not scp.

Any tips?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add a special configuration to your Mac user's ssh config, usually in ~/.ssh/config

```
Host mySpaceyUsernameHost
User "Some User"
HostName WindowsHost
```

You should then be able to scp your file using that named configuration:

```
scp myfile mySpaceyUsernameHost:~/myfile
```

I just tried this on OS X 10.7 (Lion) and it worked from one Mac to another, whereas the other options (quoted, or backlash-escaped) did not.... so that's something.

Comment: That worked like a charm.  Never heard of the config file, thank you for shedding light on what it can do!

Comment: Amazingly useful! This also works for OS/X remote hosts. I just did this to scp from OS/X to OS/X, where the remote username had a space in it.

Comment: For anyone wondering (like me) this also works for Ubuntu =) [Escape username spaces in SCP](http://askubuntu.com/a/774921/304936)

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried `Some\ User@WindowsHost`? The escaped space may work unless there is actually a bug in scp.

Alternatively could you not just change the widows 7 username and remove the space?

Comment: The backslash trick didn't work for me (OS X 10.7) I think it is actually a bug. But a configuration entry for the host did work (see my answer above).

Comment: Yes, I tried that, and it didn't work.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the spaces with underscores:

```
scp file "User Name@host":
```

becomes

```
scp file User_Name@host:
```

Working with `scp` from Linux to Mac OS X.